# Default gateway in /etc/network/interfaces is simply ignored

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

Hi there i have a problem with my linux virtual machine

**Structure:**
I am using a dedicated server from "Online.net" with an extra ip address.
On the server i have installed esxi 5.1.
For the people who want to know what server it is: http://www.dell.com/fr/entreprise/p/poweredge-r210-2/pd
The vm on the esxi server is a clean Ubuntu 12.04 (I just installed it)

**Problem:**
Every time i restart the server, my network connection is not set correct. I need to do a few extra steps to get it to work. That results in the following: Every time i reboot the server it hangs for like 1:30 minutes because it cannot find the correct network settings.

**Technical:**
To get pinging to an ip address to work i need to do this:
Code:

```
route add 62.210.123.1 dev eth0
route add default gw 62.210.123.1
```

Otherwise it just says: Network is unreachable
After that to get it fully functional i need to do this:
Code:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add: nameserver 8.8.8.8
and after that:
Code:

```
service networking restart
```

Everything works now.

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:
Code:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 212.83.168.209
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 212.83.168.0
     broadcast 212.83.168.255
     gateway 62.210.123.1
     dns-nameservers 62.210.16.6 62.210.16.7
```

**Beg:**
Can someone please help me with this issue. I am having this problem for almost 2 days now. Getting a bit desperate :P

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway (62.210.123.1) is outside of your VM subnet (212.83.168.0/24). Your IP address and your gateway should be in the same subnet (otherwise your VM doesn't know how to reach your gateway).

Comment: If that is true. How can you explain that it works after i manually type in the route it starts to work. Also i tested this on a windows vm. Same settings. Works like a charm

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t508088-default-gateway-outside-of-subnet.html

Comment: you will find quite a lot of information if you google "default gateway outside of subnet"